# R: Modelling count data as continuous variables in negative binomial regression?

Tags: r

I'm working with the count data of two species (predator and prey) and my goal is to model the density of one species ("juv_cneb_count") given the other ("carid_count"). Density = count of species/area sampled; due to uneven sampling efforts.

Due to the high number of zero's in my data, I opted for a negative binomial model. However, as I understand it, negative binomial models only accept non-negative whole numbers as a response variable (with an offset, if needed), rather than continuous responses.

How would I analyze the relationship between these two (continuous density) variables while telling R they're counts?

My data:

```
> head(df)
  juv_cneb_count carid_count Area_towed
1      0             2        383.9854
2      0            38        382.2256
3      0            25        408.3697
4      0             2        422.1000
5      0             3        165.5196
6      6             1        266.7000


    > summary(df$juv_cneb_count) # Response
       Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
     0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.4622  0.0000 15.0000

    > summary(df$carid_count) # Predictor
       Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
       1.00    2.00    6.50   40.15   31.00 1458.00
```

Plot of both variables:

[image]

My attempt:

```
nb <- glm.nb(juv_cneb_count ~  carid_count + offset(log(Area_towed)), data=dat, link = log)
```

The "offset" only effects the response variable ("juv_cneb_count") though, no?

Is this what I need?

```
nb <- glm.nb(juv_cneb_count ~  (carid_count/Area_towed) + offset(log(Area_towed)), data=dat, link = log)
```

NOTE: I added the "log()" in the offset to get rid of an an error, but not sure if it's a valid step.

Comment: Negative binomial is for counts. By dividing by the area, this is no longer count data, but rate data. There are various ways to model such data, have a look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/187843/256609)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer I received from a colleague at work. I don't fully understand it, but I hope it helps...

*I included all the variables in this model to show the model in its entirety for context.

I had multiple data points from the same stations (location), which are modeled as a random effect to account for the non-independence of observations taken from the same site.

```
nb <- lme4::glmer.nb(juv_cneb_count ~  poly(Year, 3) + I(carid_count/Area_towed) + offset(log(Area_towed)) + (1 | location), data=df)

car::Anova(nb, type = 3)

Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald chisquare tests)

Response: juv_cneb_count
                          Chisq     Df Pr(>Chisq)    
(Intercept)               578.8762  1  < 2.2e-16 ***
poly(Year, 3)              18.9251  3  0.0002833 ***
I(carid_count/Area_towed)   6.7839  1  0.0091982 **
```